# Google Doclist API : bug in revision history?

Tags: java, google-docs, google-drive-api

I'm trying to manage revisions of files (not documents) stored in google docs programatically using gdata document list java library v3.

I can create files and revisions using this tool : I can see them in the web UI. The thing is : the content of my revisions seems wrong. Here is my test protocol :

- I create a plain text file with "Hello World" in it. I upload it to gdocs without converting it.
- I create a revision of this file, its content changing to "Content of the second version"
- I create another revision, its content is now "Content of the third version"

At each step, I check the content of each revision, **using my app AND using the web UI**. Here is what I get :

- First step : no problem i see one version containing the "Hello world" text
- Second step : no problem either, i see 2 versions, containing Hello World for the first one and Content of the second version for the second.
- Third step : here the problems comes. I see my 3 versions, but only the third and last seems to be correct. when i download the second version, the content is "Content of the second versio" (not a typo, it misses the 'n'). And i cannot even download the initial version, it seems to timeout.

Important thing : I did not have this problem three weeks ago, my revision management worked well.

I have no idea of what happens there, except it seems to be server-related, as the problem is seen either with my app or the google native webapp.

Last thing : I tried using the google drive API as gdocs had been merged with drive. When i request revisions of my file, the API returns me an error saying that revisions are not supported for files, even if i can see them in the UI. I tried on converted documents, it worked.

I'm looking for a workaround for this problem. Has anyone ever encountered such a problem ?

Thanks in advance,

Jérôme

Answer (score 0, accepted):

October, 15th 2012. Google must have made something, this bug is no longer reproducible